# Reading in strings from a file and storing them in an array as an integer in C

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I'm trying to read in a file with a couple hundred integers, some positive, some negative and store them in an array. They have to be read in as a string using strtok, though. I keep getting a segmentation fault and I'm not sure why. The count is to figure out how many total integers are in the file.

```
/*Input file looks like this:
718321747   -1828022042
-1665405912 -175307986
-53757018 -1551069786 525902369
-1945908378 853648883
*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buffer[50];
    char* token;
    int count = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments\n");
        return 0;
    }
    FILE* fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    //open file
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while(fgets(buffer, 50, fptr))
    //to get the file line by line
    {
        token = strtok(buffer, "\n\t ");
        //find first token
            num = atoi(token);
            //convert it to an int
            arr[count] = num;
            //store in array
            count++;

            while(token != NULL)
            //get rest of tokens and convert to int
            {
                token = strtok(buffer, "\n\t ");
                num = atoi(token);
                arr[count] = num;
                count++;
            }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that 2nd call to `strtok()` have `NULL` as the first parameter?

Comment: Rare for me to see comments _after_ the line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never check if the token was found in the string, you must check that `strtok()` didn't return `NULL` before trying to call `atoi()`.

Then you keep scanning the same string with `strtok()` passing the string in each iteration, that's also wrong, you should pass `NULL` after the first time.

I would also recommend to use `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` to check if the conversion was successful.

Check this code, i fixed it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000 /* ? whatever value you think is good. */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buffer[50];
    int  count = 0;
    int  arr[MAX_SIZE];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments\n");
        return 0;
    }

    FILE* fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    //open file
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //to get the file line by line
    while ((fgets(buffer, 50, fptr) != NULL) && (count < MAX_SIZE))
    {
        char *pointer;
        char *token;

        pointer = buffer;
        while (((token = strtok(pointer, "\n\t ")) != NULL) && (count < MAX_SIZE))
        {
            char *endptr;

            arr[count] = strtol(token, &endptr, 10);
            printf("%d\n", arr[count]);
            if (*endptr != '\0')
                printf("error: could not convert %s to integer\n", token);
            else
                count++;
            pointer = NULL;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure it will work for you because I haven't seen the structure of your input data, but I am sure it will not cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Ok so now, it doesn't seg fault, but its only reading the first line of the input file. the structure of the data is ints separated by new lines, spaces, and tabs

Comment: @BrianHurley You should post a sample of the file's content. For this question, this is the answer and hence you have to post a new question asking why the output is not as expected.